# To use vector declared inside a function in another function

Tags: c++, memory, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void em(vector<int>* pv );

int main()
{
    vector<int>* pv = NULL;
    em(pv);
    printf("%d %d", (*pv)[0], (*pv)[1]); // Error!

}

void em(vector<int>* pv)
{
    vector<int> V;
    pv = &V;

    V.push_back(1);
    V.push_back(2);
    printf("%d %d\n", V[0], V[1]);
    // 1 2  OK!

}
```

I know vectors are dynamic assignments.
However, when the function ends, the memory seems to be freed.
I want to use a pointer to use a vector declared inside a function in another function.
What should I do?

Comment: Use `std::vector<int> em()` and just return the vector. (N)RVO will remove what looks to be a copy.

Comment: Alternatively pass a reference to em.

Comment: I need to create a vector from a function A and use that vector in B. So I tried to communicate using pointers.

Comment: @StackQ you don't need to use pointers, just return the vector itself, if you're concerned about performance then turn on your compiler optimizations and view the output assembly to make sure the object's not copied. BTW, if you're willing to allow a ptr to be passed, what do you have a against creating the vector in the scope of `main` instead of `em`?

Answer (score 2):

You can just return a vector in your function. In C++11, it moves the values rather than copying them, so returning by value isn't a problem.

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> pv = em();
    printf("%d %d", pv[0], pv[1]);
}

vector<int> em()
{
    vector<int> V;
    ...
    return V;
}
```

Alternatively by reference

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> pv;
    em(pv);
    printf("%d %d", pv[0], pv[1]);
}

void em(vector<int> &V)
{
    V.push(1);
    V.push(2);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I want to use call by ref

Comment: In C++11, it's moved rather than copied, so there's no problem to return vector by value.

Comment: As for call by ref, you can pass the vector into em as a reference, then do manipulations on it. I edited the answer to include an example.

Comment: @Eric - StackQ is clearly interpreting "call by reference" as "use pointers".

Comment: A class has a vector pointer as a variable, and I would like to make a dynamic assignment using the vector pointer of class A in the B function.

Comment: @Peter Eric's first method is to copy the vector values?

Answer (score 1):

the function em's variable vector v is temporary, when the function em return, the variable vector v's life will end, the memory will delete. You can pass a reference to function em or new a pointer in em.
if you wan't to pass a pointer you can read the below code for reference.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

void em(vector<int>*& pv );

int main()
{
    vector<int>* pv = NULL;
    em(pv);
    printf("%d %d", (*pv)[0], (*pv)[1]); 
    delete pv;
    pv = NULL;

}

void em(vector<int>*& pv)
{
    vector<int>* V = new vector<int>;
    pv = V;

    V->push_back(1);
    V->push_back(2);
    printf("%d %d\n", V->at(0), V->at(1));
    // 1 2  OK!

}
```

Answer (score 0):

variables created on the stack only last as long as the function.  When em returns, the memory behind the vector is freed.

In order to have a function which lasts longer, you would need to return a full object, or allocate the vector from the heap.

```
vector<int> em()
{
    vector<int> V;
    pv = &V;

    V.push_back(1);
    V.push_back(2);
    printf("%d %d\n", V[0], V[1]);
    // 1 2  OK!
   return V;
}
```

or

```
void em(vector<int>* pv)
{
   pv = new vector<int>();
   vector<int> & V =*pv;
   V.push_back(1);
   V.push_back(2);
   printf("%d %d\n", V[0], V[1]);
// 1 2  OK!
 // main needs to delete pv
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int>* em( );
void P(vector<int>*);

int main()
{
    vector<int>* pv = NULL;
    pv = em();

    printf("Second : %d %d\n", (*pv)[0], (*pv)[1]); 

    P(pv);

}

vector<int>* em()
{
    //vector<int> V;
    vector<int>* pV = new vector < int > ;


    (*pV).push_back(1);
    (*pV).push_back(2);
    printf("First: %d %d\n", (*pV)[0], (*pV)[1]);
    // 1 2  OK!
    return pV;

}

void P(vector<int>* pv)
{
    printf("Third : %d %d \n", (*pv)[0], (*pv)[1]);
}
```

This works.

-------result------

First : 1 2

Second : 1 2

Third : 1 2